# Convert mp3 to WAVE in java without external libraries

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Is there a way to convert a mp3 audio file into a wav audio file in java without using external libraries?

Comment: by "external libraries", do you mean no libraries that need natives or no java libraries?

Comment: obviously there is, but it is complicated. That's why somebody made JLayer, so that not everybody has to bother with the complication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tell java "hey, convert an mp3 file", it won't do that, because it isn't made for mp3.
If, however, you are comfortable with using a purely java library, then check out [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html). I have used it myself and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: Please refer following existing question with answer to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085199/mp3-to-wav-conversion-in-java

Comment: Do you mean to post JLayer as an answer there or put that into my answer here?